# Put all items of a with() results object in a string in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I faced an issue in Laravel 5.4, and a many to many relation.
I need to execute a query on a relation results.

I will explain what I want by a json result, so this is my normal result after execute this `Channel::with('categories')->get();`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "username": "ch1",
    "type": "channel",
    "members": 210424,
    "created_at": "2017-05-09 01:39:44",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-16 17:19:28",
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 32,
        "title": "cat1",
        "created_at": "2017-05-10 10:04:46",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-10 10:04:46",
        "pivot": {
          "channel_id": 87,
          "category_id": 32
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 33,
        "title": "cat2",
        "created_at": "2017-05-10 10:04:46",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-10 10:04:46",
        "pivot": {
          "channel_id": 87,
          "category_id": 33
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to have a result like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "username": "ch1",
    "type": "channel",
    "members": 210424,
    "created_at": "2017-05-09 01:39:44",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-16 17:19:28",
    "categories": "cat1 , cat2"
  }
]
```

I fact I need all categories in a string format because I have to do multiple where queries on Channel columns and on the `with` results.

**UPDATE:**

Final query that I want to do is this one:

```
Channel::orderBy('members', 'desc')
            ->with('categories')
            ->where([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members],
                ['category', 'LIKE', $category]])
            ->get()->skip($n)->take(10);
```

`$trend`, `$category` and `$n` are dynamic variables.

I need to use `skip()` and `take()` methods so I could not alter my data type from Collection to another by doings like `foreach` for every row!

Comment: `implode(' , ', $channel->categories->pluck('title'))` would do it.

Comment: But I get the categories for all rows of my channels table. or maybe I misunderstood! could you explain more? @ceejayoz

Answer (score 3):

Basically, like @ceejayoz noted, you'll want to implode the loaded categories. However, since you also want to modify the results, I suggest using a map. Something like this, although I'm not in a position where I can test the code right now.

```
$channels = Channel::with('categories')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($channel) {
        $channel->categories = $channel->categories->pluck('title')->implode(' , ');

        return $channel;
    });
```

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I can't try it right now. Perhaps it might give you a starting point? Or you could write _how_ it's not working.

Comment: It was a good learning point for me but not in this case! I updated my question, please see it.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what `$category` looks like in your query?

Comment: `$category` is just a word.

Comment: So you both have a field category and a relation categories?

Comment: In normal, categories have a object format so I could not do `LIKE' query on them, so I decided to convert them to a string to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146791/discussion-between-behnam-azimi-and-joel-hinz).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really have time for that. But I hope you find the solution! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. About your question, how it's now working, I would say when I echo or dump the channel categories directly inside map function it works but in final the result is same as results without mapping!